# Load WebView as soon as app starts

Tags: ios, webview, load

I have a WebView in my app that works fine but very slow to load.  Is there a way to actually start loading the web view as soon as the app starts?

Thanks

```
 [EconCalWebView setDelegate:self];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.forexyard.com/en/calendar.iframe?zone_id=9493"];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL];
[EconCalWebView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code for loading webview in:

`applicationDidFinishLaunching` method available in AppDelegate Class.

Here you require to load your viewController first and then load webView.

Please find more details at : [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)